# AngularJS: Animate object from DIV A to DIV B in straight line

Tags: angularjs, css, animation

Let's say I have a wizard and there's 3 segments and let's say it's like this.

[A]----[B]----[C]

Let's say A is currently selected in the scope. It's a colored red circle. When B becomes selected in the scope, it is possible to move an object (let's say a colored segment line that's 10px wide and 10px high along the segment line from point A to point B?

It would be nice to get a simple solution that figures out currently selected in scope and when that changes, calculate a straight line (it's always horizontal) and just move an object from currently selected to NEWLY selected.

How would that be done using AngularJS animations? Or can it be done using CSS3 or javascript instead?

Thanks for any pointers or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along these lines.  Not sure if this is what you wanted.

This uses ng-class, and is really only best suited for a few different linear positions. Theres probably a more dynamic, complete solution involving SASS. But I hope this helps

http://plnkr.co/edit/vMY8bSmpENj4FIv7R1yw?p=preview